# Using Regex to find multiple values (groups) in webpage

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to retrieve 2 fields from a web page. I'm using the following two patterns:

```
string paternExperience = @"Experience\s\:\s\<strong\>(?<Level>.*?)\<";
string paternAccount = @"account_value\""\>(?<Account>.*?)\<";
```

and the following method to retrieve values and it works.

```
Regex.Matches(pageBody, patern..., RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled |RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

I was trying to avoid using twice the method to retrieve 2 values, and I'm trying to create a pattern to get Level and Account in just one call of the Matches method. So I thought that something like the one below should work...

```
string paternBoth = @"Experience\s\:\s\<strong\>(?<Level>.*?)\< .* account_value\""\>(?<Account>.*?)\<";
```

But it doesn't work because I think that the two values are on diferent lines in html, so I added RegexOptions.SingleLine and now the method times out (the page has around 20kb).

Can you help me please with some advice? Thank you!

Comment: As an advice, use html-parser for such a job.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting those 2 values in 1 variable, then just check that variable with your regex.

I know it doesnt really make any sense but I try out things like that and sometimes it actually works.
Never had this scenario but I did have any simular problems in the past.
Might not be the best way. but sometimes making it work is more important then making it look pretty. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot influence the web page to have just one variable

Comment: No i mean, in your code behind.
You can check both variables.
Just make another variable where you join those 2 together and then put your regex on that.

But I would still use 2 different methods.
Making it easier to read and understand, it looks cleaner and prevent flaws ;)